# How to configure multiple Screens with Xorg on Debian

Tags: debian, xorg

Im using Debian with Xorg, there are two Monitors connected to the system.
The goal is to have two Displays/Screens with one monitor assigned to each of them.

This is the content of the xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver          "intel"
    VendorName      "Intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Device1"
    Driver          "intel"
    VendorName      "Intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen0"
        Device          "Device0"
        Monitor         "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen1"
        Device          "Device1"
        Monitor         "Monitor1"
        DefaultDepth    24
EndSection
```

With this configuration, the first monitor will be mirrored on to the second monitor.
The output from xrandr shows only Screen 0:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

How would i get the second screen in there? Is this even possible?